# Outlook - message recalled unintentionally

Tags: microsoft-outlook

So I've accidentally sent a re-call message on an email from 1 month ago. The thing is, I didn't open up any specific emails and go through the multiple actions to re-call an email.

I was sorting the emails by creating sub folders and moving them in mass to each newly created category. After 30 minutes, I was informed that I tried to re-call a message.

The only irregularity was that some emails I tried to move stated they did no longer exist. After a short period (~1min), they vanished from the inbox.

Are there other indirect ways of re-calling messages that I may not be aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there are other indirect ways of re-calling messages. Have you installed any third-party add-ins?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions under which an email recall will work are very narrow and almost
impossible to meet. If the recall either worked or failed, you should have
received a notification, if you didn't then the recall has simply failed
with no effect.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/260072/8672) of mine for the list
of conditions for Outlook recall to work.

So the most that could have happened is for the receiver of the email to have
received another email from you requesting the recall (delete) of the message.
As you didn't get a notification about his decision, this probably never happened.